# Japanese Character Encodeing

Tags: c#, api, rest, encoding

I am sending some japanese characters to my API from c# console based application, but I am not getting it properly like

> I am sending  - 配賦率登録
>   After encoding through this code -

```
HttpUtility.UrlEncode(entry.Value, Encoding.UTF8);
```

The value becomes -

> %e9%85%8d%e8%b3%a6%e7%8e%87%e7%99%bb%e9%8c%b2

which is a correct UTF-8 encoded value, but at the API end I should get

> %e9%85%8d%e8%b3%a6%e7%8e%87%e7%99%bb%e9%8c%b2 only,

but I am getting -

> éè³¦çç»é²

value which is unexpected.

//Here is my code

```
 public string CallRestMethodPost(string apiUrl, string data1)
 {
    File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\file.txt", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("こんにちは"));
    // Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
    //  data1 = "project_id=278&screen_name=01&english_uispecs_name=01_uispecs_english.xls&japanese_uispecs_name=01_uispecs_japanese.xls&function_id=dsdas&subsystem=配賦率登録";
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(apiUrl);
    // Set the Method property of the request to POST.
    request.Method = "POST";
    // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
    // string postData = "This is a test that posts this string to a Web server.";
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data1);
    File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\fileq.txt", byteArray);
    // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
    // Get the request stream.
    Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    // Write the data to the request stream.
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    // Close the Stream object.
    dataStream.Close();
    // Get the response.
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    // Display the status.
    Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
    // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
    dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
    // Read the content.
    string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
    // Display the content.
    Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
    // Clean up the streams.
    reader.Close();
    dataStream.Close();
    response.Close();
    return responseFromServer;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem it is on the content type

`request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8";`

Comment: I posted the correct one you need to include the charset. Another thing to look it is on the returning bytes if they are the same that you sent, can be a problem on the readtoend

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Base64](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524(v=vs.110).aspx) encoding your data before sending.

Comment: But I need to send the data as a stream of bytes, if i will convert the bytes in base64, then how will I send it? Please tell in details... Thanks

Comment: You send the Base64 string and then decode it back to an array of bytes on the other end. If you don't control the remote end then you will need to check the API for exactly how they want the data sent. So ContentType etc.

Comment: The API is developed in Java. Which is decoding the data using UTF-8, At the API end I should get value like - %e9%85%8d%e8%b3%a6%e7%8e%87%e7%99%bb%e9%8c%b2, but I am getting - éè³¦çç»é²